Geometry nodes mapping 0-1 UV to every mesh face
How can I achieve the "UV Reset" function in geometry nodes? Basically I want to stretch map 0-1 UV to every face in a given mesh regardless if they are rectangular or square and regardless of their size like so:


Is your question only about quads, or also about ngons?

If your mesh only consists of quads, you can solve this relatively easily with the face corner index.
As the corners of a face always follow a certain order (0 = bottom left, 1 = bottom right, 2 = top right, 3 = top left), you can determine the coordinates for your UV map with a few math nodes.
Something like this:


With Floored Modulo you get the indices 0-3 per face
With Snap (Clamped) you get the coordinates for the Y-axis
These also serve as a switch for a recalculation of the upper two indices, whereby 2 becomes 1 and 3 becomes 0, which in the end results in the coordinates for the X-axis.

